# Soundcloud PHP ubb parser

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, soundcloud, bbcode

```
$string = preg_replace("_\[soundcloud\]/http:\/\/soundcloud.com\/(.*)/\[/soundcloud\]_is", "<iframe width=\"100%\" height=\"166\" scrolling=\"no\" frameborder=\"no\" src=\"https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=\$0\"></iframe>", $string);
```

Hello once again Stackoverflow!

I would like my UBB parser to support soundcloud links, by parsing
 `[soundcloud](url)[/soundcloud]`

into

```
<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url= (url) "></iframe>
```

by using the `preg_replace` above, but this isn't working.

Can someone please help me what is wrong with my regex?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern isn't well escaped.

1. Since you use a delimiter that is not a `/`, you don't need to escape all the slashes. And closing square brackets don't need to be escaped:

   `~\[soundcloud]http://soundcloud.com/(.*)/\[/soundcloud]~is`
2. To capture the url you use a greedy quantifier `*`. It is a problem if you have more than one `[soundcloud]` tag in your string, because the capture will stop at the last closing tag. To solve this you can use a lazy quantifier `*?`:

   `~\[soundcloud]http://soundcloud.com/(.*?)/\[/soundcloud]~is`

   You can try this too:

   `~\[soundcloud]http://soundcloud.com/([^/]+)/\[/soundcloud]~i`
3. Your capture is in the first capturing group. Then his reference is `$1` not `$0` that is the whole match.
4. For your replacement string use simple quote to avoid to escape all the double quotes inside:

   `'<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=$1"></iframe>'`

Comment: Solved it with `~\[soundcloud]https://soundcloud.com(.*?)\[/soundcloud]~is` & `<iframe width="100%" height="166" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=$1"></iframe>`. Thanks for the help!